# xdiskusage marks fontconfig cache using 4 GB

Tags: fontconfig

even though `xdiskusage` marks `fontconfig` cache to be using using 4 GB, I can't find any file (even hidden ones) which exceeds 1MB, and there are only about 20-odd files in that directory.

Is this an error?

I'm using Linux Slackware64-current.

[image]